# Why are malloc() and printf() said as non-reentrant?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, reentrancy

In UNIX systems we know `malloc()` is a non-reentrant function (system call).  Why is that?

Similarly, `printf()` also is said to be non-reentrant; why?

I know the definition of re-entrancy, but I wanted to know why it applies to these functions.
  What prevents them being guaranteed reentrant?

Comment: @ripunjay-tripathi : printf, if it is printing to common resource, e.g. stdio. malloc because it rely on locks. Remember there is a difference between Reentrant and thread safety. where malloc is thread-safe. look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855763/malloc-thread-safe.

Comment: Where did you find the "canonical implementation"? Functions are reentrant if the developers say they are. glibc developers don't say malloc or printf are reentrant: so they aren't.

Comment: @pmg, the words about "canonical implementation" were added by me.  Here's what I meant.  It's obvious that reentrancy is a property of an implementation, not of an interface.  However, for example, POSIX doesn't list `malloc` and `printf` as reentrant functions, and this is for reason.  In this quesiton, the OP wanted to know what the reason is.

Comment: @pmg: and I think slightly more to the point of the question, POSIX doesn't say that `malloc` has to be reentrant, and so the glibc developers can do so and still claim to be developing "a UNIX system".

Comment: @Pavel: reentrancy *is* a property of interface as well as implementation. Required semantics are part of the interface. A reentrant interface is one of which all implementations must be reentrant. When considering the motivations of the POSIX authors, there's no "canonical" implementation. What matters is whether *any* reasonable implementation strategy, that the standards authors wish to permit, would be unable to (efficiently) implement a reentrant `malloc`. If so, then `malloc` will be marked non-reentrant, regardless of whether that implementation strategy is "canonical" or even common.

Comment: ... obviously in the case of `malloc`, almost any implementation would be expected to be non-reentrant, so the job of the standards authors was very easy.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`malloc` and `printf` usually use global structures, and employ lock-based synchronization internally.  That's why they're not reentrant.

The `malloc` function could either be thread-safe or thread-unsafe.  Both are not reentrant:

1. Malloc operates on a global heap, and it's possible that two different invocations of `malloc` that happen at the same time, return the same memory block. (The 2nd malloc call should happen before an address of the chunk is fetched, but the chunk is not marked as unavailable).  This violates the postcondition of `malloc`, so this implementation would not be re-entrant.
2. To prevent this effect, a thread-safe implementation of `malloc` would use lock-based synchronization.  However, if malloc is called from signal handler, the following situation may happen:

   ```
   malloc();            //initial call
     lock(memory_lock); //acquire lock inside malloc implementation
   signal_handler();    //interrupt and process signal
   malloc();            //call malloc() inside signal handler
     lock(memory_lock); //try to acquire lock in malloc implementation
     // DEADLOCK!  We wait for release of memory_lock, but 
     // it won't be released because the original malloc call is interrupted
   ```

   This situation won't happen when `malloc` is simply called from different threads.  Indeed, the reentrancy concept goes beyond thread-safety and also requires functions to work properly **even if one of its invocation never terminates**. That's basically the reasoning why any function with locks would be not re-entrant.

The `printf` function also operated on global data.  Any output stream usually employs a global buffer attached to the resource data are sent to (a buffer for terminal, or for a file).  The print process is usually a sequence of copying data to buffer and flushing the buffer afterwards.  This buffer should be protected by locks in the same way `malloc` does.  Therefore, `printf` is also non-reentrant.

Comment: Finally, thank you. I was about to write more or less the same, but your answer appeared just as I was starting to type mine. +1.

Comment: "any function with locks would be not re-entrant". I worked on a system where you could flag mutexes to disable signals, either just while waiting on the mutex, or throughout the time the mutex is held. Obviously it was easy to mis-use, and you have to guarantee the function would return, but it was used to access globals from reentrant functions (generally in the kernel). I assume without proof that other kernels have equivalent mechanisms, but also that the standard doesn't want to require such shenanigans where avoidable.

Comment: @Steve: For instance, in the Linux kernel spinlocks typically disable interrupts when the lock is taken. "Normal" sleeping mutexes OTOH run with interrupts enabled.

Comment: As of C11, `malloc` and `printf` are both required to be thread-safe (and POSIX has required this since 2001).  However, it's still not safe to use them from an async signal handler.

Comment: Will a reentrant lock make malloc reentrant?

Answer (score 12):

Let's understand what we mean by [re-entrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29).  A re-entrant function can be invoked before a previous invocation has finished.  This might happen if

- a function is called in a signal handler (or more generally than Unix some interrupt handler) for a signal that was raised during execution of the function
- a function is called recursively

malloc isn't re-entrant because it is managing several global data structures that track free memory blocks.

printf isn't re-entrant because it modifies a global variable i.e. the content of the FILE* stout.

Answer (score 7):

There are at least three concepts here, all of which are conflated in colloquial language, which might be why you were confused.

- *thread-safe*
- *critical section*
- *re-entrant*

To take the easiest one first: **Both `malloc` and `printf` are [*thread-safe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)**. They have been guaranteed to be thread-safe in Standard C since 2011, in POSIX since 2001, and in practice since long before that. What this means is that the following program is guaranteed not to crash or exhibit bad behavior:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *printme(void *msg) {
  while (1)
    printf("%s\r", (char*)msg);
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thr;
  pthread_create(&thr, NULL, printme, "hello");        
  pthread_create(&thr, NULL, printme, "goodbye");        
  pthread_join(thr, NULL);
}
```

An example of a function which is *not thread-safe* is `strtok`. If you call `strtok` from two different threads simultaneously, the result is undefined behavior — because `strtok` internally uses a static buffer to keep track of its state. glibc adds `strtok_r` to fix this problem, and C11 added the same thing (but optionally and under a different name, because Not Invented Here) as `strtok_s`.

Okay, but doesn't `printf` use global resources to build its output, too? In fact, what would it even *mean* to print to stdout from two threads *simultaneously?* That brings us to the next topic. Obviously **`printf` is going to be a [*critical section*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) in any program that uses it.** Only one thread of execution is allowed to be inside the critical section at once.

At least in POSIX-compliant systems, this is achieved by having `printf` begin with a call to `flockfile(stdout)` and end with a call to `funlockfile(stdout)`, which is basically like taking a global mutex associated with stdout.

However, each distinct `FILE` in the program is allowed to have its own mutex. This means that one thread can call `fprintf(f1,...)` at the same time that a second thread is in the middle of a call to `fprintf(f2,...)`. There's no race condition here. (Whether your libc actually runs those two calls in parallel is a [QoI](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quality+of+implementation%22++c+programming+language) issue. I don't actually know what glibc does.)

Similarly, `malloc` is unlikely to be a critical section in any modern system, because modern systems are [smart enough to keep one pool of memory for each thread in the system](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html), rather than having all N threads fight over a single pool. (The `sbrk` system call will still probably be a critical section, but `malloc` spends very little of its time in `sbrk`. Or `mmap`, or whatever the cool kids are using these days.)

Okay, so **what does [*re-entrancy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) actually mean?** Basically, it means that the function can safely be called recursively — the current invocation is "put on hold" while a second invocation runs, and then the first invocation is still able to "pick up where it left off." (Technically this *might* not be due to a recursive call: the first invocation might be in Thread A, which gets interrupted in the middle by Thread B, which makes the second invocation. But that scenario is just a special case of *thread-safety*, so we can forget about it in this paragraph.)

Neither `printf` nor `malloc` can possibly *be* called recursively by a single thread, because they are leaf functions (they don't call themselves nor call out to any user-controlled code that could possibly make a recursive call). And, as we saw above, they've been thread-safe against *multi-*threaded re-entrant calls since 2001 (by using locks).

So, whoever told you that `printf` and `malloc` were non-reentrant was wrong; what they meant to say was probably that both of them have the potential to be *critical sections* in your program — bottlenecks where only one thread can get through at a time.

---

Pedantic note: glibc does provide an extension by which `printf` can be made to call arbitrary user code, including re-calling itself. This is perfectly safe in all its permutations — at least as far as thread-safety is concerned. (Obviously it opens the door to absolutely *insane* format-string vulnerabilities.) There are two variants: `register_printf_function` (which is documented and reasonably sane, but officially "deprecated") and `register_printf_specifier` (which is *almost* identical except for one extra undocumented parameter and a [total lack of user-facing documentation](https://www.sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/PrintfHooksDesign)). I wouldn't recommend either of them, and mention them here merely as an interesting aside.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <printf.h>  // glibc extension

int widget(FILE *fp, const struct printf_info *info, const void *const *args) {
  static int count = 5;
  int w = *((const int *) args[0]);
  printf("boo!");  // direct recursive call
  return fprintf(fp, --count ? "<%W>" : "<%d>", w);  // indirect recursive call
}
int widget_arginfo(const struct printf_info *info, size_t n, int *argtypes) {
  argtypes[0] = PA_INT;
  return 1;
}
int main() {
  register_printf_function('W', widget, widget_arginfo);
  printf("|%W|\n", 42);
}
```

Comment: This answer is _almost_ correct; but it's missing a key concept from POSIX, _async signal safety_.  Application code _can_ execute in the middle of a call to either `printf` or `malloc` as a result of an asynchronous signal.  Neither function is required to be async-signal-safe, so it is unsafe to call them _from the handler for an asynchronous signal_.  That is what POSIX system programmers mean when they say that `printf` and `malloc` are "not reentrant".

Comment: "So, whoever told you that printf and malloc were non-reentrant was wrong"  What about signal handlers?  With threads the original thread will eventually get the CPU back and continue but with signal handlers nothing happens until the signal handler returns...

Comment: Jerry: When I gave this answer, I was under the impression that "reentrant" and "async-signal-safe" were not synonyms, and that malloc/printf are "reentrant but not async-signal-safe". Actually, I'm still under that impression; but @zwol's comment suggests that there is a significant fraction of the population that believes they *are* synonyms, and thus that any function that isn't async-signal-safe can't *possibly* be "reentrant", by definition. Sounds like Jerry is also in that camp. I guess the moral is: when using jargon, one should know one's audience and their assumptions. :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone I would personally say that "reentrant" is a poorly defined term and that one should *avoid* using it in favor of "thread safe", "recursive-call safe", or "async signal safe", which have clearer definitions.  All functions that are async-signal safe are recursive-call safe and thread-safe, and all functions that are recursive-call safe are thread-safe, but the converses are not true.  Recursive call safety is only a relevant category for library functions that call back into user code (`qsort` for instance) and it's also a term I made up just now, I don't think standards use it.

Comment: @zwol: Etymologically, it sure looks like "reentrant" should be a synonym for "recursive-call-safe," and that's how I've been using it. By the way, `int f(void (*g)()) { static int x = 0; ++x; g(); }` is an example of a function that is recursive-call-safe but not thread-safe, in that calling `f([]{})` simultaneously from two different threads will result in a data race on `x` but calling `f([]{ f([]{}); })` is completely safe. (Sorry for the C++ lambdas. Space is limited here. ;))

Comment: @Quuxplusone Oh, good point.  I tend not to write threaded code so I don't always remember all the traps.  OTOH I've seen lots of people use "reentrant" as a synonym for "thread-safe" and maybe not even recognize the *possibility* of code needing to worry about recursive invocations.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you can't start writing output while another call to printf is still printing it's self. The same goes for memory allocation and deallocation.

Comment: This explains what "re-entrant" is, but not why these functions are non re-entrant.

Comment: Oh great so. I was foolish for asking this about printf. Thanks. But can't we call malloc() from two different threads simultaneously ?

Comment: *"you can't start writing output while another call to printf is still printing it's self."*  Why?  What bit of `printf` causes that?  It's not obvious.  Maybe the result would be `Hello, woSOMETHINGELSErld!`, but all you asked would be nevertheless printed?

Comment: @RIPUNJAY TRIPATHI: It depends on the implementation, but usually malloc is thread safe if you have threading support switched on in your compilation.

Comment: @Jeremy: Are thread-safety and reenterancy one and same?  I thought they are two different things.

Comment: @RIPUNJAY: A reentrant function is also thread-safe, but a thread-safe function is not necessarily reentrant. And yes, they are two different things. For instance, on systems which support threads malloc() is typically thread-safe, but not reentrant.

Comment: @janneb: Thanks :) I knew that.

Comment: FYI, reentrant function is not always thread-safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856823/threadsafe-vs-re-entrant

Answer (score -2):

It's because both works with global resources: heap memory structures and console.

EDIT: the heap is nothing else than a kind linked list structure. Each `malloc` or `free` modifies it, so having several threads in the same time with writing access to it will damage its consistency.

EDIT2: another detail: they could be made reentrant by default by using mutexes. But this approach is costly, and there is no garanty that they will be always used in MT environment.

So there are two solutions: to make 2 library functions, one reentrant and one not or leave the mutex part to the user. They've choosed the second.

Also, it can be because the original versions of these functions were non-reentrant, so the've been declared so for compatibility.

Comment: So you claim that `malloc` is not thread-safe?  Interesting... (-1)  And you also claim that including mutexes makes the function reentrant... Even more interesting! (-2)

Comment: @PavelShved - whether malloc is thread-safe or not is an ***[arguable point](http://stackoverflow.com/q/855763/645128)***.  At least offer a reference to help clear the issue.  ***[From your own post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3941563/645128)*** do you not say it is possible that malloc can be thread ***un***safe?

Answer (score -4):

If you try calling malloc from two separate threads (unless you have a thread-safe version, not guaranteed by C standard), bad things happen, because there's only one heap for two threads. Same for printf- the behaviour is undefined. That's what makes them in reality non-reentrant.

Comment: OK, but where can it fail ? Will be good if I get some examples.

Comment: It is undefined behavior in the C specification, there is not example of where it may fail, cause at the time when writing the C specification this was a non issue (no threads at all). It might work find on some implementations and not at all on others while both implementations may follow the specification.

Comment: @RIPUNJAY: It could happen that both calls to malloc return the same pointer, because because both malloc invocations determined that block to be available (the first invocation would be interrupted between determining the block as free and marking it as allocated).

Comment: @UnixShadow:Sorry there is some problem. If there was NO threads concept at all, why RE-ENTERANCY is linked to that ?

Comment: @deadmg: thread safety and RE-ENTERANCY are different though they are related.

Comment: Thread-safety is only one of the cases for reentrancy. Another is, as mentioned, signal handlers (and other interrupt contexts).