# NETBSD 3.1 error - in malloc(): warning: recursive call

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, reentrancy, netbsd

The testing scenario is a ping to come IP and ctr+C are called from a script alternatively.

Seems like when the signal handler invoked, the ping was inside the malloc. The signal handler also called the malloc and the malloc returned with the warning  below.
    in malloc(): warning: recursive call

But still I could not find how it can cause a crash, could somebody please explain

Comment: If `triptime` is a constant and no other FP is in the code (that is `triptime*1000.0` was done at compile time), some compiles optimizes out FP routines and `printf()` with a FP specifier fails - but this is only a guess as there is so little context here.

Comment: When you say "crashes" do you mean the ping binary, the OS or something else? That certainly looks like a line from the 3.1 ping (in more recent NetBSD its different due to 64bit timings).

Also, what command line are you running and on what architecture? It could be an odd hardware/OS issue related to the specific hardware.

Comment: I updated the question, could you please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the dreaded signal handler using non-reentrant functions issue.

The problem is that the *BSD `ping`'s feature-adding-maintainers punted on doing things securely right from the beginning.

FreeBSD added this problem in 1994, noticed it in 1996 and began what should have been a much shorter path to fix the problem than it turned out to be, with the final fix sometime in 1998.

OpenBSD added this problem in 1997, noticed it in 2002 but completely missed the nature of the problem and didn't fix it properly and completely until 2015.

NetBSD added this problem in 1996 but, as you've discovered, it has not yet been fixed.  NetBSD should probably import the OpenBSD ping.

The problem is neither `malloc()` nor any of STDIO (including `printf()`) are reentrant, a necessity of all code that is used in a signal handler.

There are dozens of better places to find descriptions of reentrancy, signal handler issues, and so on, but perhaps this question and its accepted answer (and some of the related questions) would be a good start:

[Why are malloc() and printf() said as non-reentrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3941271/816536)

Comment: Thank you Greg. You are right. This is the problem. But when pressing ctr+c it is must to print the ping statistics. Do you have any idea on how can I avoid the printf  here.

Comment: I had suggested porting OpenBSD's `ping`, but I tried that and it's a lot more work than I thought it would be (though it would be well worthwhile to do).  Unfortunately the full and proper fixes necessary to avoid core dumps are probably almost as lengthy a job.  (I think porting FreeBSD's `ping` would be even more tedious)