# How to execute a "final" C code after debugging is stopped in VS Code?

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code, debugging, atexit

When you run C code in Visual Studio Code (on Linux) and stop debugging, the atexit() function is not called.

I can understand that the stop (square red button) in VS Code is similar to kill command so no further code allowed to run.

SigHandler function is not called either, see my older (not answered) question : [How to catch CTRL+C inside C Program on VS Code on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315451/how-to-catch-ctrlc-inside-c-program-on-vs-code-on-linux)

So my question is "How can I accomplish to run code (clean-up, close-up, etc.) after the debugging is ended or program-run-finished manually?

Comment: You tell your debugger to let your program continue to run, instead of killing it

Comment: Or you can detach the debugger from the process. I believe the backend is `gdb`? It has the `detach` command.

Comment: Should it matter that you don't clean up gracefully when debugging? You surely won't be using *live* data at that stage? I do realise that installing program updates on a live system can be tricky, but that isn't the place to debug.

Comment: Yes, it matters. Because I run some motors and when I stop some motors (by chance) are left in a running state.

Comment: um, repower the test rig? Or is *that* a live system?

Comment: Tell the debugger to evaluate `exit(0)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane debugging is a skill too. Hitting red square is not the greatest solution

Comment: @0___________ but that is what OP has asked. Personally, i would have a data set that is easily set up for a repeatable test, or a test rig that can be reset too.