# printf deadlock - some printf messages ignored if printf used in signal handler

Tags: c, printf, fork, deadlock

Here is a slide from System Programming course I'm currently taking:

> [image: <slide goes here>]

`catch_child` is `SIGCHLD` handler. How does the output correspond to the code? Why are some "Child #x started" messages not printed?

Comment: Presumably because of the deadlock the slide warns about.  Does the rest of the slide deck not explain what they mean by that?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941271/why-are-malloc-and-printf-said-as-non-reentrant

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No, the next slide discusses starvation. But the answers from the linked thread has answered all my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, **deadlock** is a situation when no progress is made.

So it is not that some `printf` messages are not printed/ignored, but that after some particular `printf` call the program is waiting for something that will never happen and it keeps waiting there forever.

For more info about what causes such behavior see: [Why are malloc() and printf() said as non-reentrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941271/why-are-malloc-and-printf-said-as-non-reentrant)