# What is the clearcut difference between re-entrant and thread-safe function in linux?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Threadsafe vs re-entrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856823/threadsafe-vs-re-entrant)

Could someone show me the URL where i can look at the difference between re-entrant and thread-safe concept ?

Comment: @unwind The referenced question is heavily biased on "is every reentrant function also threadsafe".

Comment: Also, all the answers given to the other question are wrong.  A reentrant function is not necessarily thread safe.  Wikipedia has an (admittedly contrived) example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)

Comment: @Whoami:  Just realised the wikipedia page in my previous comment answers your question.