# Tokenize a String in C with strtok (Include Digits as Delimiters)

Tags: c, string, tokenize

So I have the following function:

```
void tokenize() {
    char *word;
    char text[] = "Some - text, from stdin. We'll see! what happens? 4ND 1F W3 H4V3 NUM83R5?!?";
    int nbr_words = 0;

    word = strtok(text, " ,.-!?()");

    while (word != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", word);
    word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-!?()");
    nbr_words += 1;
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Some
text
from
stdin
We'll
see
what
happens
4ND
1F
W3
H4V3
NUM83R5


13 words
```

Basically what I'm doing is tokenizing paragraphs of text into words for futher analysis down the road. I have my text, and I have my delimiters. The only problem is tokenizing numbers at the same time as all the rest of the delimiters. I know that I can use `isdigit` in `ctype.h`. However, I don't know how I can include it in the `strtok`.

For example (obviously wrong): `strtok(paragraph, " ,.-!?()isdigit()");`

Something along those lines. But since I have each token (word) at this stage, is there some kind of post-processing `if` statement I could use to further tokenize each word, splitting at digits?

For example, the output would further degrade to:

```
ND
F
W
H
V
NUM
R

15 words // updated counter to include new tokens
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` is very simple in this respect: just list all the digits as delimiters, one by one - like this:

```
strtok(paragraph, " ,.-!?()0123456789");
```

Note: `strtok` is an old, non-reentrant function that should not be used in modern programs. You should switch to [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r), which has a similar interface, but can be used in concurrent environments and other situations when you need reentrancy.

Comment: Can you define `reentrancy`? I've read (today) that `strtok` is not thread-safe because it doesn't save the state or something? I've never done multi-threading, not even in Java. However, this program is just a really simple in-out text processor, not for anything serious except my own personal use.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice `strtok` is not thread-safe (and not reentrant) because it is using a global variable to keep its state. That is how it knows to continue returning parts of the string being tokenized when you keep passing `NULL` to it. If you do not plan for any concurrency, you can certainly use `strtok`, but it is a good idea to learn about `strtok_r` as well. Here is a good answer that discusses reentrancy and thread safety: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/856860/335858).

Comment: That's a great read! Considering the simplicity of this program, I think that `strtok` will work just fine. Thank you for the reference though!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use

```
    word = strtok(text, " ,.-!?()1234567890");
```

Comment: I would mark this as the correct answer because you did answer first. However, @dasblinkenlight provided explanation as well as a more desirable function to use :)