# Confusion regarding reentrant functions

Tags: interrupt, reentrancy

My understanding of "reentrant function" is that it's a function that can be interrupted (e.g by an ISR or a recursive call) and later resumed such that the overall output of the function isn't affected in any way by the interruption.

Following is an example of a reentrant function from Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)

```
int t;

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int s;

    s = t; // save global variable
    t = *x;
    *x = *y;

    // hardware interrupt might invoke isr() here!
    *y = t;
    t = s; // restore global variable
}

void isr()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    swap(&x, &y);
}
```

I was thinking, what if we modify the ISR like this:

```
void isr()
{
    t=0;
}
```

And let's say, then, that the main function calls the swap function, but then suddenly an interrupt occurs, then the output would surely get distorted as the swap wouldn't be proper, which in my mind makes this function non-reentrant.

Is my thinking right or wrong? Is there some mistake in my understanding of reentrancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question:

> that the main function calls the swap function, but then suddenly an interrupt occurs, then the output would surely get distorted as the swap wouldn't be proper, which in my mind makes this function non-reentrant.

Is no, it does not, because re-entrancy is (by definition) defined with respect to self. If isr calls swap, the other swap would be safe. However, swap is thread-unsafe, though.

The correct way of thinking depends on the precise definition of re-entrancy and thread-safety (See, say [Threadsafe vs re-entrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856823/threadsafe-vs-re-entrant))
Wikipedia, the source of the code in question, selected the definition of reentrant function to be "if it can be interrupted in the middle of its execution and then safely called again ("re-entered") before its previous invocations complete execution".

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard the term re-entrancy used in the context of interrupt service routines. It is generally the responsibility of the ISR (and/or the operating system) to maintain consistency - application code should not need to know anything about what an interrupt might do.

That a function is re-entrant usually means that it can be called from multiple threads simultaneously - or by itself recursively (either directly or through a more elaborate call chain) - and still maintain internal consistency.

For functions to be re-entrant they must generally avoid using static variables and of course avoid calls to other functions that are not themselves re-entrant.