# Random function in multi-threaded c program

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

**PLease see the whole question**

I know that `srand()` should be called only once, but my 2nd code segment shows that that does not solve the issue!!!!

The program I have written is giving me outputs which I can't quite make out why is it so. Different alterations of code segments give different outputs.

**Objective of code:**
The code uses `omp` to simply run a piece of code for 3 threads. Each thread has to print 3 random values using the `rand()` function. So, a total of 9 outputs would come. Thread `0` is the main thread/ the main program's run flow. Thread `1` and Thread `2` are the fellow new threads created at the start of code for the threads.
 **The code:**

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{


     #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            printf("\nRandom number: %d by thread %d", rand(), omp_get_thread_num());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**The output:**

```
Random number: 17105 by thread 0
Random number: 30076 by thread 0
Random number: 21481 by thread 0
Random number: 17105 by thread 1
Random number: 30076 by thread 1
Random number: 21481 by thread 1
Random number: 17105 by thread 2
Random number: 30076 by thread 2
Random number: 21481 by thread 2
```

But if I make keep the `srand(time(NULL))` before the code for thread like,

```
 srand(time(NULL));  
 #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
{
    int i=0;
    ......
    ......(rest is same)
```

The output is,
**The output:**

```
Random number: 16582 by thread 0
Random number: 14267 by thread 0
Random number: 14030 by thread 0
Random number: 41 by thread 1
Random number: 18467 by thread 1
Random number: 6334 by thread 1
Random number: 41 by thread 2
Random number: 18467 by thread 2
Random number: 6334 by thread 2
```

**The Problem, and my doubts:**

- By placing the `srand` outside, all the threads' 1st call to `rand()` gave the same random number, all of their 2nd call gave the same random number, and similarly for their 3rd call also.

  By placing the `srand` inside, the main thread's calls resulted in different random numbers than the others. BUT, the 2 new other threads among them gave the same random number for their respective calls to `rand()`.

So,

- What is actually happening here? How come the placement of the `srand()` function make a difference only to the main thread (thread `0`)?
- Why is it that either ways the the other 2 new threads always output same random number for the respective call to `rand()`?
- How is this `srand()` and `rand()` even linked, to cause this abnormality?

  And I tried giving wait intervals to each thread to remove that possibility of the `rand()` function being called by different threads at the same time, which might result in same random number maybe. But the problem was exactly like before. No change in the output (just the time at which output occurred was different).

Please help me understand this whole thing..

Comment: Move the `srand()` oustside of the block. You should only call it once when the program starts.

Comment: The 2nd code segment show that. It quite made no difference, but rather showed another anomaly by making the main thread show different values now..

Comment: I'd say this is a case of RTFM: The manpage clearly says that `rand()` isn't thread-safe and provides an alternative.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It is thread safe it's not reentrant however. But the OP actually appears to want to take advantage of the non-reentrancy.

Comment: @iharob It is not thread-safe, and other methods are mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161322/using-stdlibs-rand-from-multiple-threads

Comment: @powersource97 It is, read [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html). I don't know about Open MP but with *pthread* moving `srand()` before creating the threads works perfectly.

Comment: @iharob It clearly says >>The function rand() is not reentrant, since it uses hidden state that
       is modified on each call.  This might just be the seed value to be
       used by the next call, or it might be something more elaborate.  In
       order to get reproducible behavior in a threaded application, this
       state must be made explicit; this can be done using the reentrant
       function rand_r(). So `rand()` is not thread-safe, one needs to use `rand_r()`, but that is UNIX specific.

Comment: It's not reentrant, that doesn't mean that it's not thread safe. And I think you actually want it to always use the same seed so non-reentrancy is good for your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated**: Inserted direct answers to the OP's enumerated questions.

> What is actually happening here?

Although some versions of the `rand()` function may be "thread safe" in some sense, there is no reason to believe or expect that without any external memory synchronization, the set of values returned by multiple `rand()` calls executed by different threads will be the same as the set of values returned by the same number of calls all executed by one thread.  In particular, `rand()` maintains internal state that is modified on each call, and without any memory synchronization, it is entirely plausible that one thread will not see updates to that internal state that are performed by other threads.  In that case, two or more threads may generate partially or wholly the same sequence of numbers.

> How come the placement of the `srand()` function make a difference only to the main thread (thread `0`)?

The only thing that can be said for certain is that if the `srand()` is outside the parallel block then it is executed only by the main thread, whereas if it is inside then it is executed separately by each thread.  Inasmuch as your code is not properly synchronized, the effects of each case are not predictable from the source code, so my next comments are mostly speculative.

Supposing that `time()`, with its (only) one-second precision, returns the same value in each thread, placing `srand()` inside the parallel region ensures that every thread sees the same initial random number seed.  If they then do not see each other's updates then they will generate the same sequences of pseudo-random numbers.  Note, however, that you can neither safely rely on the threads seeing each other's updates nor safely rely on them *not* seeing each others updates.

If you put the `srand()` outside the parallel region, however, so that it is executed only by the main thread, then there are additional possibilities.  If OMP maintains a thread pool whose members are already started before you enter the parallel section, then it may be that threads 1 and 2 fail to see the effect of thread 0's `srand()` call at all, and therefore both proceed with the default seed.  There are other possibilities.

> Why is it that either ways the the other 2 new threads always output same random number for the respective call to `rand()`?

It's impossible to say with any certainty.  I'm inclined to guess, however, that none of the threads involved see each other's updates to `rand()`'s internal state.

> How is this `srand()` and `rand()` even linked, to cause this abnormality?

The two functions are intimately linked.  The purpose of `srand()` is to modify `rand()`'s internal state (to "seed" it, hence the "s" in "srand"), so as to start the psuedo-random number sequence it generates at a different (but still deterministic) point.

---

This problem can be solved in the same way that any problem involving multi-threaded access to shared variables can be solved: by applying synchronization.  In this case, the most straightforward form of synchronization would probably be to protect `rand()` calls with a mutex.  Since this is OMP code, your best bet might be to use OMP locks to implement a mutex, as it seems dicey to mix explicit pthreads objects with OMP declarations.

Comment: Excellently put. Thanks a lot! I was checking with documentations, and even they claimed that there is an internal state modified by `rand()`  and so it is not thread safe. I understood it better now. To solve the issue though, I added the thread id to each seed generation along with time(). But I actually wanted to understand the behaviour, and I finally have! And I so completely forgot about `mutex` to synchronize...

Answer (score 4):

Random number generators are actually not so random. They take some internal state (the "seed"), deterministically extract an integer from that state, and deterministically mutate the state so that it will be different on the next call.

Normally, the computations involve are complex bit manipulations intended to guarantee that the sequence of outputs "looks" random, is well-distributed over the possible range, and satisfies other requirements. But at base, it is a deterministic function on a global internal state. Without the complicated computations, it would not be much different from this:

```
# File: not_so_random.c
static unsigned seed = 1;
void srand(unsigned newseed) { seed = newseed; }
int  rand(void)              { return seed++; }
```

([Note 1])

It's pretty easy to see how that would produce a race condition if it were executed in parallel threads.

You could make this "kind of" multithread safe by making `seed` atomic. Even if the mutation were more complicated than an atomic increment, making access atomic would ensure that the next seed was the result of the mutation made by *some* call to `rand`. Still, a race condition is possible: two threads could both pick up the seed at the same time, and then they would receive the same random number. Other odd behaviours are also possible, including the one where a thread gets the same random number twice, or even an earlier one. And particularly odd behaviours are possible if `srand` is being called simultaneously with `rand`, since that is always a race condition.

On the other hand, you could protect all calls to `rand` and `srand` with a mutex, which would avoid all race conditions as long as `srand` is called before threading starts. (Otherwise, any call to `srand` in one thread will reset the random number sequence in every other thread.) However, if multiple threads are simultaneously consuming lots of random numbers, you'll see a lot of mutex contention and possibly synchronization artefacts. [Note 2].

In a multiprocessing world, library functions which depend on global state are not so great, and many of the old interfaces have multithread-safe alternatives. Posix requires `rand_r`, which is similar to `rand` except that it expects as an argument the address of a seed variable. With this interface, each thread can simply use its own seed, and the threads will effectively have independent random number generators. [Note 3]

Of course, these seeds have to be initialized in some way, and it would obviously be counterproductive to initialize them all to the same value, since that would result in each thread getting the same random number sequence.

In this sample code, I used the system `/dev/urandom` device to provide a few seed bytes for each thread. `/dev/urandom` is implemented by the operating system (or, at least, [by many OSs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random)); it produces a highly-random stream of bytes. Usually, the randomness of this stream is reinforced by mixing in random events, like the timing of keyboard interrupts. It's a moderately expensive way to generate a random number, but it will generate quite a good random number. So that's perfect for producing random seeds for each thread: I want the seeds to be random, and I'm not going to need very many of them. [Note 4]

So here's one possible implementation:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
// This needs to be the maximum number of threads.
// I presume there is a way to find the correct value.
#define THREAD_COUNT 3
// Hand-built alternative to thread-local storage
unsigned int seed[THREAD_COUNT];

int main() {
  FILE* r = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
  if (fread(seed, sizeof seed, 1, r) != 1) exit(1);
  fclose(r);

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
  {
    // Get the address of this thread's RNG seed.
    int* seedp = &seed[omp_get_thread_num()];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
      printf("Random number: %d by thread %d\n",
             rand_r(seedp), omp_get_thread_num());
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

#### Notes:

1. While that example is roughly as random as the famous [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/) on the subject, the following is an example of a `rand` implementation taken (with minor edits) straight from the C standard (§7.22.2 para.5), which is judged to be a "sufficiently-random" implementation of `rand`. The similarity with my example is evident.

   ```
   /* RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767. */
   static unsigned long next = 1;
   int rand(void) {
       next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
       return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
   }

   void srand(unsigned seed) { next = seed; }
   ```
2. Neither the C standard nor Posix requires `rand` to be thread-safe, but it is not prohibited either. The Gnu implementation of the standard C library mutex protects `rand()` and `srand()`. But obviously that is not the `rand` implementation being used by OP, because `glibc`'s rand() produces much larger random numbers.
3. If your system does not have `rand_r`, you could use a simple modification of the sample code from Note 1 above:

   ```
   int rand_r(unsigned *seedp) {
       *seedp = *seedp * 1103515245 + 12345;
       return((unsigned)(*seedp/65536) % 32768);
   }
   ```
4. If your OS does not provide `/dev/urandom`, then it is quite possible that your OS is Windows, in which case you can use [`rand_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxtz2fa8.aspx) to generate the one-time seed.

Comment: Help greatly appreciated. The internal state modification was ruining it. And thanks for pointing the problem in excessive using mutexes, when many numbers are being calculated and the issues at atomized rand. Also `dev\(u)random` is also a pretty cool way to do it. Thanks a lot for telling about that too.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `time()` has seconds precision, so each thread is calling `srand()` with the same seed leading to the same pseudo random number sequence.

Just call `srand()` once at the begining of the program and not in each thread, that would make every run of the program generate 3 different sequences one for every thread.

Comment: The 2nd code segment shows that part too. It still misbehaves!!

Comment: When you call `srand()` once I would expect a single pseudo random number sequence, each call to `rand()` would change the internal static state data and generate a new number for each call regardless of which thread calls it.

Comment: But clearly that is not the case. Please check the output that I have pasted, when the `srand()` is place outside , ie called only once.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have no clue. The whole thing is misbehaving I believe.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is thread safe, in the Linux Manual page it's explicitly stated that it is.

Comment: Also, could please answer (if you can) the way the `srand()` and `rand()` are linked? This could help understand the issue.

Comment: @iharob, my Linux Manual page for `rand()` explicitly states that "The function `rand()` is **not** re-entrant or thread safe" (emphsasis added).

Comment: Read [here please](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html), I think MT-Safe means [thread safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/attributes.7.html).

Comment: @iharob, that is a different version of the manual page than mine.  Even if you interpret it to claim that the documented version of `rand()` is thread-safe -- which does seem reasonable -- one must interpret the presence of explicitly contradictory documentation in a different version of the docs as undermining a *general* claim that `rand()` is thread safe.  In any case, the OP's implementation certainly appears not to be.

Comment: @iharob, on the other hand, the [details of what MT-Safe means](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/attributes.7.html) don't much support your implied premise that multiple `rand()` calls from different threads without any kind of external memory synchronization should yield the same collection of results, in some order, that the same number of calls all from one thread would yield.  In particular, they expressly do not imply atomicity or any kind of internal memory synchronization.

Comment: The answer to [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856823/threadsafe-vs-re-entrant) says "Functions that return statically allocated values are not thread safe without the use of a mutex, futex, or other atomic locking mechanism."

Comment: iharob and @JohnBollinger: What the Linux manpage says is irrelevant here; OP is not using glibc. (`#define RAND_MAX  2147483647`; on OP's system it is evidently much smaller, unless there's an improbability drive in the vicinity). Neither Posix nor standard C require `rand()` to be threadsafe: "The rand function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random sequence generation functions."

Comment: @rici This is totally true, I think you got it exactly as it is while I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, on your platform, `rand()` is thread safe because each thread gets its own PRNG that is seeded when the thread is created. You could get this platform to do what you want by first generating a seed for each thread and then having each thread call `srand` with its seed before it calls `rand`. But that might break on other platforms with different behavior, so you just shouldn't use `rand`.