# Interrupting a function's execution

Tags: swift, corruption, reentrancy

I found [a great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445858/9400730) explaining the re-entrancy problem but I was curious to know the various ways in which a function can be interrupted in a single-threaded environment.

```
final class Radiator {
    
    private(set) var modelName: String
    private(set) var serialNumber: Double
    
    init(modelName: String, serialNumber: Double) {
        self.modelName = modelName
        self.serialNumber = serialNumber
    }
    
    func update(modelName: String, serialNumber: Double) {
        self.modelName = modelName
        self.serialNumber = serialNumber
    }
}
```

If we created an instance of the above in memory with some initial values and then we called the update function a little later on, how would the above update function be interrupted mid execution in such a way so that the model name received a new value but the serial number did not?

Another example might be a function that opens a file, manipulates a file and then closes the file. An interruption might fail to close the file. How would that come about in a single threaded environment?

Comment: You can’t interrupt a synchronous function in a single thread environment

Comment: The linked post says 'The key for avoiding confusion is that reentrant refers to only one thread executing. It is a concept from the time when no multitasking operating systems existed.' So how can re-entrant be defined as interupting a functions execution?

Comment: The article mentions recursion and callbacks. When a recursively called function is returning the calling function is re-entered. So that is a form of interruption with reentrance

Comment: Would you like to post this as an official answer which can be voted upon @JoakimDanielson ?

Comment: No I don't see it as an answer, more a clarification of what was written in the answer you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the clarification offered by @joakim Danielson in the comments.

> An interruption in this context doesn't necessarily mean the execution
> of some other invocation is stopped. Rather, an additional invocation
> has started before the previous has been completed.